# No Logical Name for Wireless Adapter Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server

I just installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 after formatting my Windows hard drive, because I no longer need the desktop so I will be using it a server.

I cannot connect to the internet via Wireless router, and while following some instructions on a forum, I noticed that when using the command:

```
    lshw -C network
```

My wireless adapter is seen, but does not have a logical name. Is there a way to give my wireless adapter a logical name, or a different way to solve the problem? I am not able to run an ethernet wire from my router to my room at the moment so I have to find out a way to connect to the internet with the wireless adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1741865):

Had to run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```